# Automatically Send Email from Android App through Exchange Server

Tags: android, email, exchange-server, email-client

Has anyone tried sending emails automatically (without user interaction) from your android app through exchange protocol? I saw a lot of examples through SMTP and they are working perfectly. But I am wondering if it's possible to send using Exchange protocol? Does android allow to build our own exchange client?

Are there any libraries to use? Or should I build from scratch? If so, can anyone point me a good starting point?

Can anyone give me a lead? any idea? any suggestion where to start looking at? or anything?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The exchange protocal (depending on how things are set up) is nearly always RPC over HTTP/HTTPS as a mobile user. ActiveSync is the alternative but has few advantages.

An issue you may come up against is MS Exchange has client access policies that require the Exchange server to have certain amount of control over the phone (Mandatory PIN Lock, remote wiping of phone etc that probably need root access). There are also Certificate trust requirements.

If you are developing an in house platform it may be quicker to look at IMAP which exchange does reasonably well.